# regular expression for Indian mobile numbers, Email Id and Password : React Js || Next Js

Tags: reactjs, validation, authentication, email-validation

This is regex for indian local mobile number validation and for Indian international .

starting with 9,8,7 you can add more as well.

Email and Password

Hear is the code

Please Subscribe making Videos soon
[My Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1t4QhR5Yl0YINMlkI2cfPg)

````
    const status = validate();
    if (status === true) {
      alert('Login');
    }
  };

  const doSignUp = () => {
    const status = validate();
    if (status === true) {
      alert('Sign Up');
    }
  };

  const validate = () => {
    if (
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(
        email
      ) &&
      email.includes('.')
    ) {
      if (
        /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,99}$/.test(password)
      ) {
        if (
          /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d{9}$/.test(
            phoneNumber
          )
        ) {
          return true;
        } else {
          alert('Invalid Phone Number');
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        alert(
          'Invalid, Password should contane Capital Letter, Small Letter , Number and Symbol'
        );
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      alert('You have entered an invalid email address!');
      return false;
    }
  };```
````

Answer (score 0):

````
    const status = validate();
    if (status === true) {
      alert('Login');
    }
  };

  const doSignUp = () => {
    const status = validate();
    if (status === true) {
      alert('Sign Up');
    }
  };

  const validate = () => {
    if (
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(
        email
      ) &&
      email.includes('.')
    ) {
      if (
        /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,99}$/.test(password)
      ) {
        if (
          /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d{9}$/.test(
            phoneNumber
          )
        ) {
          return true;
        } else {
          alert('Invalid Phone Number');
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        alert(
          'Invalid, Password should contane Capital Letter, Small Letter , Number and Symbol'
        );
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      alert('You have entered an invalid email address!');
      return false;
    }
  };```
````